# Why are Indian phone numbers automatically prepending a 0 in Maz-UI

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3, phone-number, libphonenumber

I am using Vuejs's Maz-UI framework, and specifically their [phone number inputter](https://louismazel.github.io/maz-ui-3/components/maz-phone-number-input).

But there is an issue; when selecting Indian phone numbers, I type in some random 10 digit string of numbers.

But instead of showing the (formatted) phone number on screen, it adds a `0` to the front of the input.

Here's an example:

This is the expected result:
[image]

This is the actual result:

[image]

Sorry for not taking a screenshot for the expected result; when I tried to take it, it automatically re-formatted it the wrong way.

Does anyone know why this occurs? I don't think this is the correct formatting of Indian numbers.